# Siecore template field type resolution and solr when performing search query with sort

Tags: solr, sitecore

I'm trying to perform a search sort using Sitecore 9.3 and SXA. The default search configuration allows the user to sort by 'Title'. The search logs shows queries with `&sort=title_t desc` which is expected.

If I change the sort criteria from `Title` to `Other Title` via `/sitecore/content/[site name]/Global/Settings/Facets/Title` to a field other than title, I no longer get results from the search results call.

Looking in the search log shows that `Other Title` is not being resolved to `other_title_t` with the error `ERROR Solr Error : [sort param field can't be found: other_title ]`

The Sitecore documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/using-solr-field-name-resolution.html described the mechanism for resolving fields to the correct type using index config

```
  <fieldType
    fieldTypeName="html|rich text|single-line text|multi-line text|text|memo|image|reference"
    returnType="text"
  />
  ...
</fieldTypes>
```

which is then used with the the type match to append `_t` to the field name

```
<typeMatches hint="raw:AddTypeMatch">
  <typeMatch
    typeName="text"
    type="System.String"
    fieldNameFormat="{0}_t"
    cultureFormat="_{1}"
    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration,
      Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"
  />
</typeMatches>
```

This does not appear to be working for sort.

I've found that adding the **fieldName** (rather then rely on the preconfigured **type** mapping ) works and result in `other_title_t` being used as the query sort.

```
<fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="other title" returnType="string" />
            </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>
```

Should sort field resolution work via type field mapping already? Is this a bug?

Comment: it may be because for sorting the fieldtype for the field should be of type string....

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti not sure what you mean, the template field ‘other title’ is a single line text field.

Comment: sorting does not working on text field type...field type should be string

Comment: But it does work when &sort=other_title_t

Comment: does the fields with name "other_title" exist at solr end?

Comment: yes other_title_t exists in solr